# java.lang.VerifyError: Bouncycastle

Tags: logging, jenkins, console

I have two `Jenkins` servers; in one the job is successfully built and in the other the `Jenkins` job tests are failing

I get the following error:

> java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/bouncycastle/XXX/XXXSignedHelper, method:  signature: ()V) Incompatible argument to function at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData.(Unknown Source)

Comment: What code have you used? Can't really help you if don't know what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi Samuel, I am just making a maven build with javacode . Recently migrated jenkins from one server to another server both with same configuration. I mean jenkins,maven and bouncycastle version are same . The same build is running on one server . When i was trying in another it was failing some test cases